# Bigquery - 'Having' does not work as expected

Tags: google-bigquery, having

I have the query:

```
SELECT date(date) as day, App, count(*) as cnt,
avg(cnt) over (partition by App) as avg_per_day

FROM [DATABASE]

group by date,two_hour, App
```

Now I basically want to stay only with Apps that have on average more then 5 downloads a day. However, when I add `having avg_per_day>5`, I get

> Field 'avg_per_day' not found.

Also entering `where avg(cnt) over (partition by App) > 5` does not work.

What am I doing wrong?

I don't want to use double `SELECT` due to the fact that every query costs money and they are supposed to run every hour.

Thanks

Comment: Using `window functions` with `group by` the way you do in your last two questions look very suspicious. You might get totally wrong result w/o any error. To be on safe side - I would recommend you to carefully qc your approach. I suspect an issue here.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

OVER() functions run after the HAVING step - so at the HAVING stage the column `avg_per_day` still doesn't exist.

Instead of:

```
SELECT date(date) as day, App, count(*) as cnt,
avg(cnt) over (partition by App) as avg_per_day
FROM [DATABASE]
group by date,two_hour, App
having avg_per_day>5
```

Try:

```
SELECT day, App, cnt, avg_per_day
FROM (
SELECT date(date) as day, App, count(*) as cnt,
avg(cnt) over (partition by App) as avg_per_day
FROM [DATABASE]
group by date,two_hour, App
)
WHERE avg_per_day>5
```

Cost wise should be the same.

Comment: You could also use QUALIFY and then wouldn't need the subquery. QUALIFY runs after HAVING and WINDOW. https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/reference/standard-sql/query-syntax#qualify_clause